# SSISDB [catalog].[get_parameter_values] procedure return null values for in job parameters

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a couple of job imports created in SSIS where I have defined a parameter called: **VAccount** for each one of them. 
As I understand, SSISDB database contains all info about my jobs and there is one stored procedure that should allow you to retrieve the parameters value used inside your jobs by executing the following stored procedure:

```
EXEC    [catalog].[get_parameter_values]
        @folder_name = N'Vendor Import',
        @project_name = N'Dcs.SupplierImport',
        @package_name = N'Wave.dtsx',
        @reference_id = NULL
```

Unfortunately my output shows that VAccount parameter has its value NULL, while in my import it has a default value: 64039050.

Is there anything I am missing here??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set the value of the `VAccount` parameter in SSDT?  To retrieve the default parameter values using `catalog.get_parameter_values` set these in the SSIS catalog.  To set a default parameter value from the catalog right-click the package and select **Configure...** then click the ellipsis in the Value field for your parameter and enter the default value in the Edit Value field.  This will now show up in the result set of `catalog.get_parameter_values`.

Comment: That worked. I still don't understand why the field is not updated when having the 'Use default value from package' setting checked.